# Bivector/multivector notation

Tags: notation, clifford-algebras, geometric-algebras

In linear algebra, vectors are often distinguished from scalars by putting a small arrow above the variable i.e. $\vec{v}$. In some contexts, it would be useful to have a similar way to distinguish a bivector from scalars, vectors, or trivectors. Is there a commonly used way of doing this, such as a rotating arrow above the variable? When talking about magnetic fields, $iB$ is often used, but I'd rather just be able to denote the magnetic field as a bivector rather than treating it like a vector and converting it with $i$.

Answer (score 3):

In [Electromagnetism using Bivectors](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0143-0807/1/3/013/meta), an ellipse over the letter is used to indicate bivectors, other than that, I couldn't find any other unique notation.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with the `\hat` symbol as many authors use that to denote an entity that has been normalized (e.g. $\hat{B}\widetilde{\hat{B}} = 1$. In the literature/books I've read, a capital letter does seem to be the most universal for elements with grade higher than one, and the actual grade appears to be inferred from the context.

(note I would have preferred to just write a comment for this, but my karma isn't high enough for that :P)

Answer (score 0):

Some authors write $\hat{B}$ for a bivector $B$, but most use plain letters (no bold face, nor over arrow) for anything with grade higher than 1.